# Macbook Pro (mojave) can't connect to new router

Tags: network, wifi, password

my landlord set up a new router and provided me a new password. However, i am unable to connect to the internet.

After typing in the password, I get an error that says 'The wifi network requires a WPA2 password' and "Invalid password"

Initially, I thought that I should have used the security key instead, but that also returns the same error.

I the went to open network preference -> advanced, and created a new preferred network. However, this also returns the same error ('The wifi network requires a WPA2 password' and "Invalid password")

Can anyone point me to suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Can you connect any other device to this WiFi network?  This type of error message usually means there’s a problem with the password being used.  Also be sure to disconnect anything connected to your Mac while trying to connect.  One more thing, you can try to forget the existing WiFi network and create a brand new connection to the landlord’s WiFi.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, did your landlord give you the correct passkey?  Speaking as the owner of a couple rentals, I can tell you that once he provides internet, he becomes Tech Support for that router whether he likes it or not and should assist you in getting connected just like any other ISP